# why is my for loop in PL/SQL not printing out the last iteration

Tags: database, oracle, for-loop, plsql

I am creating a PL/SQL script that gets an expense number and then  it gets the total of cash used for the expense, the amount of credit used for the purchase, the total of the expense, and the total amount paid.  I am using a FOR loop to accomplish this for each expnum in my table.  After it gets these values, it looks to see if the totalPaid is less then or equal to the total of the expense.  When my loop runs, it outputs information for expNum 1 through 4 even though I have 5 in my table.  I can not figure out why the script is not running 5 times and is stopping after the 4th execution.  Below is my script.  Any tips/ help is greatly appreciated thank you.

```
DECLARE
  lineTotal NUMBER;
  cashPaid NUMBER;
  creditPaid NUMBER;
  totalPaid NUMBER;
  expNumMax NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(EXPNUM)
    INTO expNumMax
    FROM EXPDET;

  dbms_output.put_line ('EXP num max is: ' || expNumMax);

  FOR expNumCounter IN 1..expNumMax
  LOOP
    SELECT SUM(Amt)
      INTO lineTotal
      FROM EXPDET
      WHERE ExpNum = expNumCounter;

    SELECT CASHAMT
      INTO cashPaid
      FROM EXPMAST
      WHERE ExpNum = expNumCounter;

    SELECT SUM(Amt)
      INTO creditPaid
      FROM ExpByCc
      WHERE ExpNum = expNumCounter;

    totalPaid := cashPaid + creditPaid;

    IF totalPaid < lineTotal THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('SELECT * FROM expmast');
    END IF;

    IF totalPaid = lineTotal THEn
      dbms_output.put_line ('EXPNUM is: ' || expNumCounter);
      dbms_output.put_line ('Line Total is: '|| lineTotal);
      dbms_output.put_line ('cashPaid is: ' || cashPaid);
      dbms_output.put_line ('Credit Paid is: '|| creditPaid);
      dbms_output.put_line ('Total paid is: ' || totalPaid);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Perhaps you have duplicate values of `EXPNUM` in your table or perhaps the values start at 0 rather than 1.  Also, you can probably do what you want using analytic functions, but it would be easier to know if you provided sample data and desired output.

Comment: Your code will also fail if you do not have a contiguous series of `expnum` values - i.e. a gap in those numbers. For a start, the second select inside the loop would get `no_data_found` for a non-existent value. If you did want to do this in a loop as an exercise, you could bulk select all `expnum` values into a collection and iterate over that instead. But that still wouldn't be the most efficient way to look at this data.

Comment: You might want to consider using a cursor FOR loop over the EXPDET table instead of using a value FOR loop. In my experience value FOR loops are hardly ever useful in PL/SQL, while cursor FOR loops are the bread-and-butter of the language. YMMV. Share and enjoy.

Comment: As already discussed, there is most certainly a better way to solve this issue, but maybe you have `totalPaid > lineTotal` for the last line? In this case you do would not write anything...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not have so many records in EXPDET you run out of memory the following code should do what you require.

(Note: I haven't run the code as I don't have your data structure)

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_EXPDET IS
    SELECT EXPNUM
      INTO expNumMax
      FROM EXPDET
    ;
  TYPE t_EXPDET IS TABLE OF c_EXPDET%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;  
  l_EXPDET t_EXPDET;

  l_cur NUMBER;

  lineTotal NUMBER;
  cashPaid NUMBER;
  creditPaid NUMBER;
  totalPaid NUMBER;
  expNumMax NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_EXPDET;
  FETCH c_EXPDET BULK COLLECT INTO l_EXPDET;
  CLOSE c_EXPDET;

  l_cur := l_EXPDET.FIRST;
  WHILE (l_cur IS NOT NULL) LOOP
        SELECT SUM(Amt)
          INTO lineTotal
          FROM EXPDET
          WHERE ExpNum = l_EXPDET(l_cur);

        SELECT CASHAMT
          INTO cashPaid
          FROM EXPMAST
          WHERE ExpNum = l_EXPDET(l_cur);

        SELECT SUM(Amt)
          INTO creditPaid
          FROM ExpByCc
          WHERE ExpNum = l_EXPDET(l_cur);

        totalPaid := cashPaid + creditPaid;

        IF totalPaid < lineTotal THEN
          dbms_output.put_line ('SELECT * FROM expmast');
        END IF;

        IF totalPaid = lineTotal THEN
          dbms_output.put_line ('EXPNUM is: ' || l_EXPDET(l_cur));
          dbms_output.put_line ('Line Total is: '|| lineTotal);
          dbms_output.put_line ('cashPaid is: ' || cashPaid);
          dbms_output.put_line ('Credit Paid is: '|| creditPaid);
          dbms_output.put_line ('Total paid is: ' || totalPaid);
        END IF;

        l_cur := l_EXPDET.NEXT(l_cur);
  END LOOP; --Loop through EXPDET  

END;
/
```